# redirect from blogger to my mobile site

Tags: javascript, html

how can I redirect from blogger to my mobile site ?

I have try to put some codes in the  and it doesnt work.

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/detecting-and-redirecting-mobile-users/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think You want to detect mobile devices using `Javascript`

Add:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 window.location.href="http://My-Mobile-Site.com";
}
</script>
```

between your `<head>` tags, Now whenever someone visits your blog with a mobile device they will redirected to your mobile site